# How to set header variables in GraphQL-SPQR

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-spqr

I'm running a GraphQL API using GraphQL-SPQR and Spring Boot.

At the moment, I am throwing `RuntimeException`s to return GraphQL errors. I have a `customExceptionHandler` that implements `DataFetcherExceptionHandler` that returns errors in the correct format, as shown below:

```
class CustomExceptionHandler : DataFetcherExceptionHandler {
    override fun onException(handlerParameters: DataFetcherExceptionHandlerParameters?): DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult {


        // get exception
        var exception = handlerParameters?.exception
        val locations = listOf(handlerParameters?.sourceLocation)
        val path = listOf(handlerParameters?.path?.segmentName)

        // create a GraphQLError from your exception
        if (exception !is GraphQLError) {
            exception = CustomGraphQLError(exception?.localizedMessage, locations, path)
        }

        // cast to GraphQLError
        exception as CustomGraphQLError

        exception.locations = locations
        exception.path = path

        val errors = listOf<GraphQLError>(exception)

        return DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult.Builder().errors(errors).build()
    }
}
```

I use the `CustomExceptionHandler` as follows (in my main application class):

```
@Bean
    fun graphQL(schema: GraphQLSchema): GraphQL {
        return GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema)
                .queryExecutionStrategy(AsyncExecutionStrategy(CustomExceptionHandler()))
                .mutationExecutionStrategy(AsyncSerialExecutionStrategy(CustomExceptionHandler()))
                .build()
    }
```

I'd like to set a header variable for a UUID that corresponds to the exception, for logging purposes. How would I do that?

Even better, is it possible to create a Spring Bean that puts the UUID in the header for all queries and mutations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when you're using spring boot, there's two options:

- you're using the spring boot graphql spqr starter (which brings it's own controller to handle all graphQL requests)
- you're using plain graphql-spqr and have your own controller to handle GraphQL requests

In any case, you've got a few options:

#### Making your CustomExceptionHandler a Spring Bean and Autowiring HttpServletResponse

That would probably be the easiest way to go - and it would probably work in any case: You could simply make your CustomExceptionHandler a Spring bean and have it autowire the HttpServletRequest - in the handler method, you could then set it to whatever you would like it to be. Here's some dummy code in Java (sorry, I am not proficient enough in Kotlin):

```
@Component
class CustomExceptionHandler implements DataFetcherExceptionHandler {
    private final HttpServletResponse response; 

    public CustomExceptionHandler(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response; 
    }

    @Override
    public DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult onException(DataFetcherExceptionHandlerParameters handlerParameters) {
        response.setHeader("X-Request-ID", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        // ... your actual error handling code
    }
}
```

This is going to work because spring will realise that HttpServletRequest differs for each request. It will therefore inject a dynamic proxy into your error handler that will point to the actual HttpServletResponse instance for every request.

I would argue, that it's not the most elegant way, but it will certainly solve your problem.

#### for the graphql-spqr spring boot starter

There's a [default controller implementation](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/io/leangen/graphql/spqr/spring/web/GraphQLController.java) that is used in projects using this starter. That controller will handle every graphql request that you receive. You can customise it, by implementing your own [GraphQLExecutor](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/io/leangen/graphql/spqr/spring/web/GraphQLExecutor.java) and making it a spring bean. That executor is responsible to call the GraphQL engine, pass the parameters in and output the response. Here's [the default implementation](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/io/leangen/graphql/spqr/spring/web/servlet/websocket/DefaultGraphQLExecutor.java), that you might want to base your work on.

Similarly to the previous solution, you could autowire the HttpServletResponse in that class and set a HTTP Response header.

That solution would allow you to decide, if you want to set a request id in all cases, or just in specific error cases. (`graphql.execute` returns an object from which you can get the information if and what errors existed)

#### when using graphql-spqr without the spring boot starter

Locate your GraphQL controller, add an argument to that method of type HttpServletRequest - and then add headers to that as you prefer (see previous section on some more specific suggestions)